# When rendering an image in shiny using R, the elements underneath the image don't fully move down

Tags: r, image, shiny

What is the correct way of adding a rendered image and for the elements below to move accordingly to its size in a dynamic way?

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Image and Element Below in a Shiny App"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Notice the text is over the image instead of below")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      imageOutput("myImage"),
      textOutput("myText")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # Path to the image (replace with your own image path)
  imagePath <- "~/path/to/image"
  
  output$myImage <- renderImage({
    list(src = imagePath,
         alt = "Image",
         width = "100%", height = "auto")
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
  
  output$myText <- renderText({
    "This is the text underneath the image."
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I've tried adding `footer = hr()` but it is not dynamic and doesn't respect the "end" of the image space either.

I've also noticed this behaviour happens when the image is long.

I'm using shiny v1.8.0 and seen this behaviour in several different OS.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `imageOutput` has a `height` argument set to `400px` by default. If you set it to `"auto"`, as in your `renderImage`, you get the result you want.

```r
imageOutput("myImage", height = "auto")
```

Comment: Amazing, that's exactly the behavior I'd expect now. Thanks for the hint. Strange `height = "auto"` is not the default value.